# How can I pass this value to a label in another web page in my project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get what was entered into txtProjectName from the CreateProject Page, and then put it in a label with a message in it as well, it seems like everything I try will not work.

I put this in the page 'Congratulations.aspx'

`<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Pages/CreateProject.aspx" %>`

In 'Congratulation.aspx.cs', this is in Page_Load

```
lblCongratsMsg.Text = PreviousPage.ProjectName + "has been........"
```

And in the 'CreateProject.aspx.cs page I have this...

```
    public string ProjectName
    {
        get
        {
            return txtProjectName.Text.Trim();
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How do you go from `CreateProject` to `Congratulations`? Do you use a Button or a LinkButton with `PostBackUrl`? That would allow you to use `PreviousPage`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I have a button that you click that is validating all the information, and then if it was all inserted into the database properly, then it takes you to the next page. I've been using `Response.Redirect("~/Pages/.aspx")`

Comment: You could follow the suggestion given by @DrewKennedy (but deleted now): use a `Session` variable.

Answer (score 0):

See the following tutorial:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0100__Page-Lifecycle/CrosspagepostVBnet.htm

The important bits:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Runat="server" Text="Submit page to itself" 
     OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" Runat="server" Text="Submit page to NextPage.aspx"
     PostBackUrl="NextPage.aspx" />
```

To use `PreviousPageType` you'll need to do a cross page post, not postback to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

To move data from one web page to another you can use various state management techniques provided by ASP.NET, such as:

- Session State
- Application state
- Query Strings
- Cookies

I would suggest reading up on them and learning when you should use which - [ASP.NET State Management Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx)

Here's a simple example using query strings:

**1st Page - Capture the data and redirect the user to the second page:**

```
protected void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = String.Format("Congratulations.aspx?data={0}", txtData.Text);
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

**2nd Page - Read the value from the query string and display in a `Label` control:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblData.Text = Request.QueryString["data"].ToString();
}
```